# I get a 302 error when I use websocket in my code

Tags: amazon-web-services

I made an alarm system by using websockets.

It worked on localhost.

But after I put my project on AWS and the domain that I bought, I got an 302 error message with details as below:

> `login.htm:125 WebSocket connection to 'ws://52.79.243.89:8080/Apollo/socket.htm' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302`

And this is my code:

```
var wsocket;
function connect() {
    wsocket = new WebSocket("ws://52.79.243.89:8080/Apollo/socket.htm"); 
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate that 'I put my my project on AWS'? Is it a container? Is it an HTTP Server on an EC2 instance etc.

Comment: Yes What you said is What I wanted to say